# URL mapping with more variable parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can have URL in more formats:

```
site.net/Controller/Function/AnyStringProperty
site.net/Controller/Function/AnyIntProperty
site.net/Controller/Function/AnyStringProperty/AnyIntProperty
```

In controller i can write any logic for Property1 and Property2, but it seems like dirty way.

Other way is write something like
site.net/Controller/Function/AnyDefautlForStringProperty/AnyIntProperty

except

site.net/Controller/Function/AnyIntProperty

Is any possibility how to do this in routes.MapRoute function? Or in other place then in controller?

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Controller/Function",
"Controller/Function/{AnyStringProperty}/{AnyIntProperty},
new { controller = "Controller", action = "Function", AnyStringProperty = "", AnyIntProperty = ""}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

Here's what I've used in the past:

```
       context.MapRoute(
            "default_sub_resource",
            "prefix/{controller}/{resource}/{subresource}/{action}"
        )

        context.MapRoute(
            "default_resource",
            "prefix/{controller}/{resource}/{action}"
        )

        context.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "prefix/{controller}/{action}"
        )
```

I inlcuded the paramters before the action, but you can put them where-ever you like.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it, but i afraid that after it URL will not so cool... :-)